# Loop though HTML ID in Python

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble with looping through these IDs in Python.
I used beautifulsoup to parse a website and would like to loop through TD in these 5 TR:

**id="dgrDispill_DXDataRow0** to **id="dgrDispill_DXDataRow4**

I tried to use something like this:

```
i=0
for tr in tableau_main.findAll('tr'):
    for td in tr.find(id = "dgrDispill_DXDataRow"+'i'):
        i+= 1
```

Thanks in advance.

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3XKi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've put quotations around 'i' in line 3.

Also, you could clean up the code:

```
for i in range(5):
    for tr in tableau_main.findAll('tr', {'id':'dgrDispill_DXDataRow' + str(i)}):
        Do stuff...
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks!